# Stumped by Behaviour when Finding Multiples

Tags: python, c++

I'm sure this is just me being really stupid, but the progam I'm writing is showing behaviour that I just can't understand. The progam looks for a number divisible by all the numbers between 1 and 10 (this is a precursor to a Project Euler solution).

My code works - here it is in Python:

```
for i in range( 1, 10000 ):

    check = 1

    for j in range( 2, 10 ):
        if i % j == 0:
            continue
        else:
            check = 0
            break

    if check == 1:
        print i
        break
```

And it correctly finds the lowest such number which is 2520. I wanted it to be more efficient, and I thought if you just see if it's divisible by the numbers from 6 to 10, you'll be testing the same thing.

However, change it to

```
for j in range( 6, 10 )
```

and it returns 504! I've written it in both C++ and Python and they both do the same thing - I really don't get it! And it's just so obviously wrong - it clearly isn't even divisible by 10!

I can't understand why my code suddenly stops working when this is changed. I particularly don't understand why testing for multiples in the range 6 to 10 is not logically equivalent to the range 2 to 10.

For those more partial to c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    for( int i = 1; i < 10000; i++ ){

        int check = 1;

        for( int j = 6; j < 10; j++ ){

            if( i % j == 0 ){

                continue;

            } else {

                check = 0;
                break;

            }

        }

        if( check == 1 ){

            cout << i << endl;
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `range(6,10)` doesn't give what you think.  It'd produce `[6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: To elaborate, for getting numbers in the range `m` to `n` (both inclusive), you need `range(m, n+1)`.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl's answer is correct. As an aside, if you're in python 2.x, you should use ``xrange`` and not ``range`` for for loops. ``range`` produces the actual list, ``xrange`` just produces a generator that produces the numbers in the list as you iterate over it, so it's much more efficient especially for large numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose not knowing this about Python is OK, but I can't believe I didn't realise this when actually writing out `j < 10` in the C++!

Comment: Just as a programming style aside, it tends to be more readable if you use boolean types for these flags as opposed to integers. For example in Python `check = True` and in c++ `bool check=true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `range( 6, 10 )` means all the numbers starting from 6 inclusive and up to but not including 10. So only the numbers 6, 7, 8, 9.

`range( 2, 10 )` works because it includes 5, together with the other included numbers like 6 or 8 that require it to be devisible by 2, so you actually got an (implicit) check if it's devisible by 10 included in it even if 10 isn't part of `range(2, 10)` either.

You could write `range(5, 10)` or `range(6, 11)` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `5`.

```
range9(1,10) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
range9(6,10) == [6, 7, 8, 9]
```